# Website shows Java not installed

Tags: java, jre

When I try to use Screenleap it asks me to install Java. However, I have `openjdk` and `icedtea` already installed.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Here's what you need to do to make it work: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by *ThiagoPonte* the answer is located at this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk).

I'm marking this as answered.